# Overcoming unexpected behavior of NSURL's checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError

Tags: ios, nsurl

In a program I am creating for iOS 5, I am experiencing unexpected behavior with the checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError method of NSURL.

I created a new project to verify the issue and included only the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSError *err = nil;
if([url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]){
  NSLog(@"URL is reachable");
}else {
 NSLog(@"URL is not reachable");
}
```

Further, I tried:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSError *err = nil;
[url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err];
if(err == nil){
 NSLog(@"URL is reachable");
}else {
 NSLog(@"URL is not reachable");
}
```

...still to no avail. The result is always, "URL is not reachable", contrary to stackoverflow.com (and other domains I tested) obviously being reachable. How does one utilize this function to check if a resource is reachable?

Comment: Your error checking is wrong. **Always** check the return value to know if something succeeded or not. **Never** rely on the error pointer for this; it is there to provide additional information as requested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError%3a) for `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` state:

```
Returns whether the resource pointed to by a file URL can be reached.
```

Note: "file URL", not Internet or other scheme URL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I must have missed that.