# Detect new network connection or disconnection

Tags: objective-c, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to detect a connection on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-a-connection-on-ios)

How can you detect a new connection to a network or a disconnection in Objective-C in Mac OS X?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-a-connection-on-ios)

Comment: Is [SCNetworkConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConnection/Reference/reference.html) what your'e looking for?

Comment: @AlonAmir Could you provide an example for using it?