# Check before calling webservice internet is On or Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, reachability

Want to check is **Internet** is available or not-available before calling any **WEB-SERVER**.

I used the Reachiablity which provided by apple to check the internet is on or off.
I added this two files into my project.
**Reachability.h and Reachability.m**

In ViewController.h

```
 -(BOOL)connected;
```

and ViewController.m its Implementation.

```
   -(BOOL)connected{
        Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
        return networkStatus != NotReachable;
    }
```

before calling webserver making an condtion

```
if([self connection] == true){

// Do call web server.
}

else {
// Alert message print. // Please check internet connection.
}
```

When running the application in both case with **WIFI ON or OFF** with MACBOOKPRO "Simulator" or on Device. Its always returns true condition.

Please let me know, what should i need to do properly for making reachablity work.

I am using Xcode 6.0.1 IOS SDK 8.0.

@ALL
Thank In Advance.

Comment: pls check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-internet-connection-on-ios

Comment: its work for Device not for simulator.  There is small issue in reachability in IOS 8.0  issue fixed in IOS 8.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother? If there's no network connection, you'll get a perfectly good error back from your attempt. Reachability is useful for knowing when a connection has returned, if you had network jobs queued up, but it's pointless to check before every web call.

You need error handling code anyway, because a missing connection is only one of several reasons a request could return an error. In this case reachability is adding extra code for no benefit, which is true of most uses I've seen.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  But if there is no network connection I do get good error back.  Here Un-necessary i am making a call to server, I felt this is not an efficient one.   -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error Message %@" , error);
]

}

Comment: How do you think reachability gets its information?

Comment: about reachability gets its information.  Its only status of network Is On or Off.  Not related with request server data.

Comment: It uses a remote host and checks that it can connect to it. That's the same thing you'd do anyway when making your web call, except possibly to a different host.

Comment: @ Jrturton I am sorry!! You are absolutely correct.  Positive vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AFNetworking library then it internaly check network connection and gives proper network error alerts.
REF: http://afnetworking.com

Answer (score 0):

I did a test on iOS 8, the above code works on device. But on simulator, it is always returns true no matter wifi is on or off. After changing the reachability to:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
```

it worked on simulator.

The original code works on simulator with iOS 7. So possibly a bug for iOS 8.

Comment: I have small question here.  With out calling www.google.com  reachabilityWithHostName can i able to get network status. On or Off

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe in the future you can.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
if (![self connected]) {

   // Alert message print. // Please check internet connection.
 } else {
  // Do call web server.
}
```