# Device supported network connections in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application i need to retrieve network types that device supports .Not currently  available active connection ,

i have gone through with these links , but they shows you the available connection , not the device support network connection

[Easiest way to detect Internet connection on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-internet-connection-on-ios)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to know which network types that device supports , like  3g and  4g