# iOS swift 4 Add notification listener for network connection status from any class

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, network-connection, reachability-swift

I am using [ashleymills/Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) to check network connection status. When I use it in a particular class in `viewWillAppear` method, it works just fine.
But currently I have more that 40 classes and I don't think I need to implement the notification listener in each of them.
So, I have been trying to run it in `AppDelegate`'s `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. I tried for one class, like, if I have a class named **DashboardVC**, I wrote:

```
var reachability = Reachability()!
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
let vc = DashboardVC()
Notificationcenter.default.addObserver(vc, selector: #selector(reachabilityDidChange(notification:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: nil)
return true
}
```

And the **reachabilityDidChange(notification:)** function:

```
func reachabilityDidChange(notification: Notification) {

let reachability1 = notification.object as! Reachability  
switch reachability1.connection {  
case .wifi:      
   print("Reachable via WiFi")  
case .cellular:      
   print("Reachable via Cellular")  
case .none:    
   print("Network not reachable")  }
}
```

But this didn't work when I turned on/off the internet connection or switched from wifi to cellular network right when **DashboardVC** was the `topmostViewController`.
Please help me:

1. If there's a way to achieve my goal with [ashleymills/Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)
2. If there's a way to achieve this without [ashleymills/Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)
3. If there's any other way to keep track of network connection status

Regards!

Comment: checkout here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710600/6898523

Comment: @MAhipalSingh Thanks a lot! But where do I implement this to keep observing for all classes?

Comment: you can create a global function.

Comment: In this case your instance of DashboardVC will destroyed after return, so there is no any observers which subscribed to your observable.

Comment: Okay. Thanks much! @MAhipalSingh

Comment: @V.Khambir That's true. I never thought of that.  Thanks for this!

Comment: @MAhipalSingh how to add observer for a View controller from app delegate