# How to handle internet connection status Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if an device (in this case an IOS device) has access to the Firebase Realtime Database.

So I have created this method:

```
private func isConnected(completionHandler : @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
   let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
       connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            completionHandler((snapshot.value as? Bool)!)
       })
}
```

This method is working perfect. And I'm using it like this in every method where I'm doing something with the realtime database:

```
isConnected { (connected) in
    if(connected){
         //do your things
    } else {
       print("network error")
    }                       
}
```

But now my question, what if you get the network error. How do you know if your device has no internet connection or the Firebase service is down? What is a good approach to do this? Because the only thing I know right now is that I can't reach the realtime database.

So my question is, how can I get more detailed information? Isthe device offline? Is firebase down? etc etc.

Comment: Use reachability.

Comment: For an Android client, a connection exists only when needed.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) explains: _On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity._ I don't have experience with iOS, but would expect it to be the same...

Comment: So when  `.info/connected` returns false, is may mean a connection is not possible, or a may mean a connection is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's `.info/connected` only signals whether your app is connected to its Firebase Database backend. It does not detect general network connectivity.

To determine the latter, try one of the many answers from [this list]. Including [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx), [Easiest way to detect Internet connection on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-internet-connection-on-ios), and [Check for internet connection with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift).